# Recording function in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am heading a problem when developing an app.
I would like to implement recording function in `UIPageViewController`. 
And my storyboard is like this : ShowViewController embed pageViewController embed ContentViewController.

But every time that I change the page, recorder will reset again so that user can't record when they read whole book at same time. Please help me with this. How can I implement recording function when user reading book at same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... not 100% sure what your current layout is like but I'm going to take a stab at it and say that your recording function is within one of the embedded view controllers and not in the overall pageViewController. Your recorder is probably resetting (maybe in the viewWillAppear?) every time you leave and rejoin an internal ViewController. Can you post some code?

Comment: Dear David : Your are right~!! I think the reason that I couldn't record is the recording code implement in view Controller. I've think to write recording code in UIPageViewController but I couldn't add UIButton or any target-action in PageViewController. Do you know how to solve it?? BTW I am pretty sure that recording function is normal but It will false when I change the page.

Comment: You need to create a delegate for you "internal" view controllers so that you can access the button actions in the PageViewController. Here's a pretty good resource on what delegates are and how to use them.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/

Comment: Dear David : Thanks for your solution.From delegation design pattern, I've also tried notification function between "internal" ViewController and PageViewController , it works !! Thanks!!